# elevateZoom function is not calling in my jquery on mouse hover but alert is working?can any one help to complete the task

Tags: jquery, zooming

elevateZoom function is not calling  in my jquery  on mouse hover but alert is working? Here is my link : http://lotusvalue.com/color-park/zoom.html 
 once loaded click layout link, on that first image , I have applied the zoom code.kindly share your knowledge, where I went wrong. This is the first time applying zoom function
Here is my  Html code:

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="layout">
<a href="list2.php" style="color:#550b0d;"><h2 class="text-uppercase mt-0 line-height-1 text-center">Click Here To see Phase -II 12 Acres ,27 Guntas Availability List</span></h2>
<img id="zoom_01" src="images/layout/12 acre.jpg" class="img-responsive"  data-zoom-image="images/layout/12 acre.jpg">
</a>
</div>
```

Here is my zoom code:

```
<script src='jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
<script src='jquery.elevatezoom.js'></script>
<script>
alert('ok')
$('#zoom_01').elevateZoom({
zoomType: "inner",
cursor: "crosshair",
zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
zoomWindowFadeOut: 750
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: in your site you have a 404 error on jquery 1.8.3 inclusion... look at the console...

Comment: this means? any conflict. How to overcome this one?

Comment: delete the line where you call jquery 1.8.3 you already have 2.1.4 version loaded

Comment: Deleted ,but no zooming is coming when mouse over,check again, but alert is working, next which part we need to check

Comment: I stopped sliding code also and I checked the zoom code, it is not reflecting. guide me what shall we do, I need the jquery zoom effect......what it try to achieve

Comment: it worked to me after adding `width="400"` to the `img` tag

Comment: I did that not reflecting to me,can you connect with screen share. I want to see that, where i went wrong , correct me

Comment: sorry I can't share my screen...

Comment: but it is not reflecting at my end, which browser you are checking i checked chrome and firefox

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hLyac3zf/ here you can find a fiddle

Comment: same thing i applied in the layout , it is not coming, some other thing it is conflicting and also i stopped slider code after that also not coming, what next should try

Comment: start from the demo. It works on your browser?

Comment: check this i  tried this also not working, what code you have given and uploaded to server  http://lotusvalue.com/color-park/zoom.html now you could figure out easily where we went wrong

Comment: try to delete the alert or put a semicolon after it...

Comment: removed alert , no reflection ,

Comment: does the code in my answer work for you? start from there...

Comment: updated the code as per your wording, no reflection at any movement kindly have a look http://lotusvalue.com/color-park/zoom.html

Comment: look at the console, you have to put the scripts inside the <head> before you call elevatezoom

Comment: i updated that also , not showing zoom, check the code please we make this one success, i update online only

Comment: you didn't... put it online

Comment: http://lotusvalue.com/color-park/zoom.html

Comment: don't you see the error in the inspector?

Comment: it says `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $`that means that you are trying to use jquery before it is loaded... so first load jquery and elevateZoom and after call elevateZoom

Comment: yes it shows like this only Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?  I put the cdn code on head section ,further please support

Comment: now console is not giving any error, but not output?

Comment: ok, now change the small image and put a smaller one...

Comment: changed no reflection , here is the path http://lotusvalue.com/color-park/zoom.html

Comment: it means you should use a small image for src attribute and a large one for the data-zoom-image attribute

Comment: applied http://lotusvalue.com/color-park/zoom.html  no changes

Comment: please try publishing this https://pastebin.com/0mhj0tvZ

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this. It works...

```js
$('#zoom_01').elevateZoom({
  zoomType: "inner",
  cursor: "crosshair",
  zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
  zoomWindowFadeOut: 750
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/elevatezoom/3.0.8/jquery.elevatezoom.min.js'></script>
   <a href="#"> 
<img id="zoom_01" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="img-responsive" data-zoom-image="https://via.placeholder.com/500">
   </a>
```